# apache2 cannot start with default-ssl.conf included

Tags: ssl, apache2, ssl-certificate

==== Required information ====

- iRedMail version:  `iRedMail-0.8.6`
- Store mail accounts in which backend `(LDAP/MySQL/PGSQL)`: MySQL Initially, then MariaDB

I installed the latest `iRedMail-0.8.6`. Every thing is running smoothly, even when I install mariadb which replace mysql, apache2 still running. After update/upgrade my ubuntu, apache still running.

Until when I shutdown and booting again another time, my apache2 cannot start with default-ssl.conf included, but if it's not included, apache2 can start normally. Because of that, i cannot run the webmail which need ssl.

Heres my default-ssl.conf: http://pastebin.com/MDPMtBgN

My apache2 error.log: http://pastebin.com/xFMAfSmd

Any help would be appreciated? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest upgrade iredmail because it now support latest ubuntu 14.04. If it is still failed, just fresh install all iredmail components.
Cheers

Comment: yes, i think it's better choice because i already mess around with it but no luck.